# Unable to connect to kafka using PublishKafka in NIFI in my local system

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am trying to push message into my kafka topic using InvokeHttp but it shows a connection error.
[image]

**InvokeHttp** is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add kafka listener in the `server.properties` file inside the `conf` directory.

```
# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

After that turn on the broker. This time it should work.